# Password hash not working with single quotes

Tags: bash, perl, hash, solaris

I'm trying to hash a password using the crypt hash function in Perl. In a Bash script so far I have:

```
password='Pa$$word'
hashedPassword="$(perl -e "print crypt('$password', 'salt'), \"\n"")"
```

I then modify/copy /etc/shadow using sed:

```
sed -e '/^user1:/s_:[^:]*:_:'"$hashedPassword"':_' /etc/shadow > /tmp/shadow
```

The method works, except when passing a string containing single quotes. How can I handle a password containing ' single quotes? Running Solaris 10 OS.

Comment: How are you calling `sed`? Single quotes shouldn't be special within this command. For example: `hashedPassword="start'end" && echo '/^user1:/s_:[^:]*:_:'"$hashedPassword"':_'` prints `/^user1:/s_:[^:]*:_:start'end:_`, which looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in bash.  Trying to set a shell variable containing a single quote by enclosing it in single quotes will not work.  Per the man page:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the  literal  value  of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Supply the password as a parameter to your one-liner instead of interpolating it directly in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

password='Pa$$word'
hashedPassword=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "salt"), "\n"' $password)

echo "p='$password', h='$hashedPassword'"
```

**Output:**

```
p='Pa$$word', h='saFQXTeqbkiIQ'
```

Comment: Can I convince you to come to the London Perl Workshop this year? Drop me a mail and we can have a chat. :)

Comment: @simbabque Wow! London?! Let me think about that. I'm so in love with that city :-)

Comment: There you go: http://act.yapc.eu/lpw2017/ the London one is traditionally on a Saturday, and it's free. Unfortunately the trip is more expensive, compared to others. You did miss Hamburg and The Perl Conference in Amsterdam. That one was reasonably close to you I think, wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As password contains `$` and `$` are syntactical in perl it is not easy to pass in hard in script, other options are to pass by arguments or by environment.

```
# by argument
perl -e '($password, $salt)=@ARGV;print crypt($password, $salt), "\n"' "$password" "$salt"

# by environment variable
password=$password salt=$salt perl -e 'print crypt($ENV{password}, $ENV{salt}), "\n"'
```